# PHP language translation using .po an .mo file

Tags: php, linux, gettext

I am using below command to convert po to mo using php for gettext translation.

```
exec("msgfmt messages.po -o messages.mo");
```

If execute same command on CLi it works fine but through php its not converting po to mo file.

Please suggest me If i am missing something.

Comment: how do you define $path ? please check its value first.

Comment: that is fine. I echo and executed same from command prompt it works fine but not from php file

Answer (score 0):

Few steps to get it working:

- Check disabled functions in php.ini and remove 'exec' from list:

  disable_functions=""
- exec can be limited by safe_mode. You can turn safemode off in httpd.conf:

  php_admin_value safe_mode off
- Check .htaccess in your web folder, may be some settings are overwrited here.
- Check the user php runs as:

  echo exec('whoami');

  and then add correct permissions to used files and executed command.
- Use full server paths in command:

  exec("/full/path/to/msgfmt /full/path/to/messages.po -o
  /full/path/to/messages.mo");

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to "use the tools", and avoid reinventing the wheel.

Take a look at this nice piece of open source code : https://github.com/josscrowcroft/php.mo

> php.mo is a couple of functions that take an input (.po) file and
>   generate an output (.mo) file. Usage is easy:

```
<?php
    require('php-mo.php');
    phpmo_convert( 'messages.po');
?>
```

Hope this helps !